# WordPress not updated correctly

Tags: upgrade

I have hosted my website with grendlehosting site.I have my domain is being hosted there with wordpress installed. I had WordPress 2.x. then I tried to update my WordPress to 4.1. but after the update,my site shows that the  site is under maintain.please help for solving the problem

Comment: You can update WordPress manually http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions

Comment: if your site shows the "Scheduled maintenance..." notice you can look for and remove a file in the root of the WP installation called `.maintenance`